# Getting error when i start mongodb 4.0 service

Tags: mongodb

Error:

```
2020-04-09T09:21:54.019Z I CONTROL  
  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify 
  --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
  about to fork child process, 
  waiting until server is ready for connections.
  forked process: 20642

  ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

Comment: share full error stack and the command